# Azure AD B2C customized login page - Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I wanted to customize the standard AD B2C login page which I have been able to do following the instructions, but the only requirement I have to is to add my apps logo at the top of the login page.  Otherwise, the default looks fine.

Unfortunately, using the customized version, you lose all the styling and it looks terrible.  Anybody know where I can get the CSS that MS uses for the default version of the page?

Right now I am using the free version which is fine for now.  I gather there is branding option when you go to paid sub but I would rather not go there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the source of the page you are interested in, and then search for the corresponding .cshtml file. For example, for the sign-up/sign-in page, this would be the cshtml link:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/default/unified.cshtml

You can then look at the CSS in that file, and use it as needed.